# Excel 2010 VBA Creating ActiveX ListBox gives 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm trying to use this code to clear all ActiveX objects then create an ActiveX ListBox.  Creating the ListBox results in an 'Object doesn't support this property or method'.

```
Sub DeleteActiveXObjects()

    Dim oOBJECT As Shape

    For Each oOBJECT In Sheets("Search").Shapes
        If oOBJECT.Type = 12 Then oOBJECT.Delete
    Next oOBJECT

    ActiveSheet.Select

End Sub


Sub CreateListBox()

    Dim oLISTBOX As OLEObject

    Set oLISTBOX = Sheets("Search").OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.ListBox.1")

    Sheets("Search").ListBox1.Object.IntegralHeight = False
    Sheets("Search").ListBox1.Object.Font.Size = 11
    Sheets("Search").ListBox1.Top = 220.5
    Sheets("Search").ListBox1.Left = 20
    Sheets("Search").ListBox1.Width = 1100
    Sheets("Search").ListBox1.Height = 500.25

End Sub
```

However if I separate the code into one Sub that creates the ListBox then one to set the Properties and if I manually execute them, it works fine.  If I execute the two separated Subs from a third Sub, I get the same error as above.

In case the problem has to do with how quickly Excel tries to set the properties after creation of the ListBox, I tried Application.Wait and then using the Sleep API, each for 2 secs, but that doesn't help.

Any ideas on how to find the problem is appreciated

Comment: Which line specifically are you getting the error message? Did you try setting as many properties for the listbox in the `.Add` statement as possible? See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195728.aspx)

Comment: I can't tell which line causes the error.  I step to Set and then the message 'Can't enter break mode at this time' so it's either Continue and the rest executes or End are my choices.   I had not considered putting the properties in the .Add statement.  I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead. It ensures you are setting the properties of the listbox being created:

```
Sub CreateListBox()

    Dim oLISTBOX As OLEObject

    Set oLISTBOX = Sheets("Sheet6").OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.ListBox.1")
    With oLISTBOX
        .Object.IntegralHeight = False
        .Object.Font.Size = 11
        .Top = 220.5
        .Left = 20
        .Width = 1100
        .Height = 500.25
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked.  Thank you.  Any ideas as to why it doesn't work the way I had coded it?  I clear out all the ActiveX controls and the ListBox created is definitely #1 but somehow Excel doesn't see it that way.